# how to handle click events happening at the same time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

my system is all about sending remittances to different places in the world. i sometimes find a scenario by which 2 different users do the following:

1. User1(the remittance payer) clicks "pay" button for paying it.
2. User2(the remittance sender) clicks "return" button for returning it.

These 2 events occur at the same time thus leading to the system confused with which event is to be considered/handled first !

Q:  Is there a way of considering one event by ignoring the other event ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'at the same time' isn't a thing in JS, the events should be two different calls into the event handler which happen one after another. even if an event occurs at the same exact nanosecond, the js event handler will still have to process them separately

Comment: In the future Node will be multithreaded, but for now it's single threaded so you can't have race condition because all the events are put in a queue for serialized handling.

Comment: @CCC Please give an example of the unwanted behavior that you observed.

Comment: @Dominique Fortin, similar unwanted behaviors observed are:

For settlements page, we have 2 buttons:
1. "Confirm" button
2. "Reject" button

when these buttons are clicked at the same by 2 users, the system handles both events differently instead of considering one event.

Comment: @Dominique Fortin,
2. When 2 users click "return" button at the same time, the system considers both clicks as 2 different clicks. Thus leading to return duplicates in transaction entries table !

Comment: whatever server api you may use, search for server name Queue hook, for e.g if you are using redis server I suggest you to use Kue.js for queuing

Comment: @CCC 2 users making an event each always translate to 2 separate transactions. This is totally normal. Why do you thing it is abnormal?  Also, are the 2 users competing for the same resource?

Comment: @CCC Are the 2 users on the same computer?

Comment: @CCC Normally, events are handle with a "first arrived, first served" policy.  Which means that if 2 users are competing for the same resource, only the first user will get the resource and the second user will receive a message informing hin the the resource is no longer available.

Comment: @Dominique Fortin
"Are the 2 users on the same computer? "

Ans: No but different computers.

I got your last point with the policy, "first arrived, first served".  Thanks, i will just keep thinking of how these disgusting behaviors should be handled.